# Labor theory of value examples and exercises

Tags: reference-request, marxism

I'm looking for a working book of Marx's Labor Theory of Value. It would be nice if the book would explain his theory with calculated examples and some exercises with solutions that one can do. Since I'm a German I could read The Capital for myself, but I find it too complicated. Any good books on this?

Comment: You could start by skimming through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_value or the shorter (but with a bibliography in English and German) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wertgesetz though subject to usual Wikipedia caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [these slides](https://www.postkeynesian.net/downloads/kingston13/JW110713.pdf), which includes a fairly introductory analysis to the LTV, including some trivial examples and calculations.

Another introduction can be found [here](http://www.marxist.com/marx-marxist-labour-theory-value.htm) (part one) and [here](http://www.marxist.com/marx-marxist-labour-theory-value2.htm) (part two).

Yet, [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/29790106) is the best I am aware of. It is an attempt to explain the theory to "undergraduates" using a simple example. Worth reading!

Answer (score 0):

Eric Fromm has written great analyses of Marx (Marx's Concept of Man). His central argument is showing that Marx was a Humanist (and his political writing derived from that point) and that he has a son of the Enlightenment. It was a fascinating read where he used a number of Marx's works that are rarely seen in English (although that shouldn't be a problem for you). [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0826477917) is the link to the book.

Comment: This answer could be improved with some more specific citations and perhaps an excerpt.

Comment: How does this answer the specific question of the OP, which was about Theory of Value "tutorials" and not about Marx's works in general?

Comment: One of the chapters specifically concerns Marxs LtV